# "Confirmation for" versus "confirmation of"

Tags: phrase-usage

I've seen people use both *confirmation for* and *confirmation of*, and I'm wondering if they mean the same thing or they have slightly different implications.

> After you are done reviewing the attached essay, please confirm your receipt **of** it.

> After you are done reviewing the attached essay, please confirm your receipt **for** it.

I think the second usage is wrong because I've seen people use "x.com order confirmation **for** your recent order", but not  "x.com order confirmation **of** your recent order".

They seem interchangeable, but at some point they don't seem.

I guess I basically have two questions. I didn't even realize I was asking about "receipt of/for".

Which of the following sentence is correct?

> I need your confirmation **for** the essay I sent you.

> I need your confirmation **of** the essay I sent you.

I think that *of* is definitely more common, but can *for* be correct in this case? I'm so confused about this usage that I usually leave everything out and say "please review the attached essay and confirm receipt." Is this a full, grammatically acceptable sentence?

Comment: Without context, neither "I need confirmation *for* the essay I sent you," nor "I need confirmation *of* the essay I sent you" makes sense. You don't confirm an object. You confirm an action.

Comment: *your receipt **of** it* = *the **act** of you receiving it* (so *confirming* that means *verifying the fact that you **did** receive it*. Whereas *your receipt **for** it* would normally be understood as a reference to a ***sales slip / counterfoil*** (given to you when you bought it, for example; this isn't something you'd normally be asked to "confirm").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is confirmation **of** receipt **of** the essay.

This is not only ugly, it is potentially confusing, because **a** receipt is **a** confirmation **of** receipt **of** the essay; and we call that a receipt **for** the essay.

This is what happens when people use nominalized verbs instead of actual verbs. Your instinct to turn those nominals back into the verbs they come from is commendable. Do so at every opportunity.

> After you have reviewed the essay, please confirm that you received it.

Three verbs, no nominals, no prepositions.

Comment: How about my simple version? Does "Please review the essay and confirm receipt" make sense? I'm just wondering if I have been using an ungrammatical example. Thank you!

Comment: @jess That's fine, it's grammatical, and it won't be misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *confirmation [for,of]* it's *receipt [for,of]* that you are asking about.

In the first sentence [*receipt*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/receipt) means  the act or process of receiving.   The request asks that you confirm that you have received something.

In the second sentence *receipt* is a noun meaning proof of purchase- actually a written acknowledgement from the seller that they have received payment for goods or services.  The request is asking that you confirm that you possess that written acknowledgment.

A receipt *for* something always means the written acknowledgement.
Receipt *of* something always means the reception of that thing.

In your case, the second sentence is probably incorrect because, in context, it isn't very likely that they are asking to see your proof of purchase for the essay; they want to see you acknowledge that you received it.

Answer (score 0):

This both phrases are using in different occasion. If yo have confirmation regards to any matter then you can use "confirmation of". The "confirmation for" is using in the case of the confirmation is not clear about the matter
:)

Comment: I _think_ that somehow you are trying to convey the correct message, but it gets drowned in the abundance of ungrammatical constructions and typos.